# How to upgrade Ubuntu from update manager?

Tags: upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 10.10. and update manager says that Ubuntu 11.04 is available.

But when I pressed the upgrade button, it says `fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.`

But my net is working fine, so what is the problem???

Comment: Paste the contents of `/etc/update-manager/relese-upgrades`. Also, try to do it from command line => `do-release-upgrade`. Otherwise, you can try to use 12.04 or later ISO to do the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.10 and 11.04 and the next version after 11.04 (11.10) ALL have reached EOL (End Of Life). They are not supported anymore. No updates, no new packages, no community support..etc.

Please read the list [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

So you cannot upgrade from an unsupported version to another unsupported version. The only thing you can do is to download an .iso image of a supported version: [12.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/) or [12.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/) or [13.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/),  burn it to a CD/DVD or [USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) , then boot from there and upgrade or have a new install. Your will see the options at Installer window.

PS: Ubuntu 12.04 is the current LTS version and will be supported until April 2017.